# Is there a way to set multiple values for the same property of a node in AGE?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have a graph with train stations, where each station belongs to at least one line. I would like to make several stations belong to 2 lines and am not sure how to do so. Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('Train', $$
    CREATE (:Station {name: 'Station 1', line: 'Line 1', 'Line 2'})
$$) as (n agtype);
```

But this will not work as each property only takes one variable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list in order to store multiple values for a property.

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('Train', $$
CREATE (:Station {name: 'Station 1', line: ['Line 1', 'Line 2']})
$$) as (n agtype);
```

Reference: [Data types](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html) in AGE

Answer (score 0):

Depending on data type and database architecture other alternative approaches to Lists would be:

1. Using Maps:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('test_graph', $$
    CREATE (:Station {name: 'Station 1', line: {line_1: 'available', line_2: 'unavailable'})
$$) as (n agtype);
```

2. Using Maps of Lists:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('test_graph', $$
    CREATE (:Station {name: 'Station 1', line: {available: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], unavailable: [4, 5, 8]})
$$) as (n agtype);
```